# How do I get unique values after getRespondentEmail in google apps script?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-forms

I've been trying without success to get unique values from an array, after creating the array from *getRespondentEmail* in google apps script. I've tried to use the set method, the forEach etc for this and each time it returns an empty array or empty curly brackets. This is a sample of my code:

```
function test(){
  var form = FormApp.openById('...');

  form.setCollectEmail(true);
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();

  var getEmails = [];
  var uniqueResponses = [...new Set(getEmails)];

  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];
    var oneEmail = formResponse.getRespondentEmail();
    getEmails.push(oneEmail);
  }

  Logger.log(uniqueResponses);

}
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I'm stuck. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function test(){
  var form = FormApp.openById('...');

  form.setCollectEmail(true);
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();

  var getEmails = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];
    var oneEmail = formResponse.getRespondentEmail();
    getEmails.push(oneEmail);
  }

  var uniqueResponses = [...new Set(getEmails)];
  Logger.log(uniqueResponses);
}
```

- In your script, when `var uniqueResponses = [...new Set(getEmails)]` is run, `getEmails` has no value. By this, your issue occurs. In this modification, `var uniqueResponses = [...new Set(getEmails)]` is used after `getEmails` has the values. By this, the duplicated values are removed.

#### Reference:

- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)